# Content not displaying for anyone other than Admin

Tags: users

I have a problem with Drupal 7. I recently set up Context module to display some blocks on given conditions and everything seemed to be fine. However, when I logged out every text in a block within a Mini panel disappeared on front page, and on every internal page content body (title still visible) is gone too.

I flushed the cache several times. In permissions anonymous and other users have "view published content"(this is a lazy translation from french) enabled. In didn't apply any kind of user role condition in Context, nor do I have any css/js error in console. Other than those which are only alerts:

> Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[En savoir plus]jquery.min.js:1
>
> L’utilisation de « getPreventDefault() » est obsolète. Utiliser « defaultPrevented » à la place.

Please help me through these darks times...I'm running out of options

Thx in advance

Comment: Have you checked the text formats permission.

Comment: Thx for your anwser, checked! Everything seems fine. I don't see how this would fit to my problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
So...In fact I verified the permissions of a body field of a block within a mini panel (yeah right...) and there were no permissions for anonymous user to view. So I checked that for only one block and somehow it all went right without changing anything else. So there's that.

Thx anyway for your precious time.